# Tombstone warning with SELECT LIMIT 1

Tags: cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ck INT, 
    pk INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ck, pk)
);

for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    sessionRW.execute(QueryBuilder.insertInto("test").value("ck", 1).value("pk", i));
}

root@cqlsh:ks> select * from test limit 5;

 ck | pk
----+----
  1 |  1
  1 |  2
  1 |  3
  1 |  4
  1 |  5

(5 rows)


root@cqlsh:ks> delete from test where ck = 1;

root@cqlsh:ks> insert into test(ck,pk) values (1, 0); -- new minimal value
root@cqlsh:ks> select * from test limit 1;

 ck | pk
----+-------
  1 | 0

(1 rows)

WARN  11:37:39 Read 1 live and 9999 tombstoned cells in ks.test (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 1 columns was reque
```

Why when I do a SELECT with "LIMIT 1" I get the tombstone warning ?

The rows are order by pk ASC and the lower pk value of this table (0) is the first row and is not deleted.

I don't understand why cassandra keep scanning my table for other results (hence fetching a lot of tombstone) because the first row match and I specified I just want one row.

I could have understood the warning If I didn't specified LIMIT. But what's the point of scanning the whole table when first row match with LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I think I found the answer, the answer is cassandra is doing one more lookup after limit 1 (like if you did limit 2).

Just insert one more row:

```
insert into test(ck,pk) values (1, 1);
```

and now `select * from test limit 1;` won't trigger a tombstone error.

However, if you do LIMIT 2, it will trigger a tombstone error even if we have 2 valid rows, first in the table order.

Why cassandra is doing (limit+1) lookup is the question.

Answer (score 3):

Because the way cassandra stores data. The data is stored as a single wide row as columns even if it looks through cql like multiple rows. Therefore in order to get to the lastly inserted "row" it needs to read all tombstoned columns as well.

Below is an illustration

```
    | 1 | 2 | 3 |...|9999| 0 |
----+---+---+---+---+----+---+
ck=1| T | T | T | T |  T |   |
```

As you can see it is one row under a clustering key 1. I marked tombstoned columns (or rows if you prefer) with "T". Cassandra reads the entire row, and then in order to find first non-tombstoned column, it needs to cycle through all 9999 tombstoned ones.

Comment: but if insert (1,1), (1,3), (1,2) select will outpt 1,2,3 and not 1,3,2 so it's using the index not the insert order

Comment: I have to use = 0 to make cassandra use the index and avoid tombstone, why can't it walk it through the index if nothing specified

Comment: It does not store data in the same shape and in the order it outputs it. And there is no index too :)

Comment: Funny that I was on the meetup today where Jon Haddad gave exactly this example as why cassandra is not a good choice for implementing queues

Comment: Your explaination can't be valid for two reasons: first just insert 0-10000 then delete 1-10000, following your example, first column (0) won't be tombstonned , however, it will still trigger a tombstone error. Secondly, I'm sure Cassandra insert columns in clustering key order, if not it would takes ages to process the where, and it would still trigger tombstone error when you restrict where = .

Answer (score 0):

When you do "select * from test limit 1;", Cassandra has to go to all the nodes and filter the entire table to find the first live row.  It needs to stream the tombstones to the coordinator since other nodes may be out of sync and the limit 1 would match a row that had been deleted.  You should be able to avoid this by specifying the query such that the tombstones wouldn't matter, such as "select * from test where ck=1 and pk < 1;"

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to restrict the partition key ck, however it's not the reason why it did trigger the tombstone error, I was doing test in single node cluster.